# Is it possible to send html tag hyperlink , audio and video in Facebook chat?

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-chat, facebook-chatbot

I wnat to send html hyperlink as  my website  in facebook chat . But chat box read it as text . can it is possible that i send html tag in chat. Same case for html tag audio and video . I can send video and audio link in chat . But i want to run audio or video in chat box with my friends using html tag. It is possible or not in facebook chat . Thanks in advance

Comment: No you can't use HTML

Comment: @WizKid , 
 
My friend  sent youtube link to me in facebook chat it fetch video image and title . But when i chat with chatbot ( i developed it)   it send me same youtube link , but this link does not fetch video image and title from youtube . Can it is possible that fetch youtube video title and image in user's chatbox when i send youtube link via chatbot on facebook .